# SQL Instead of insert trigger

Tags: mysql

I have these tables:

```
Aircraft(acID, acNAME, range)  
Employee(empID, empNAME, salary)  
Certification(empID, acID)
```

And this view:

```
CREATE VIEW AircraftPilot AS
SELECT empNAME, salary, acNAME, range
FROM Employee e, Certification c, Aircraft a
WHERE c.empID = e.empID AND c.acID=a.acID;
```

I have to create an instead of trigger to insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO AircraftPilot (empNAME, salary, acNAME, range) VALUES ('John', '3000', 'BOEING 737', '4500')
```

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and triggers are highly vendor specific). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_AircraftPilot 
ON AircraftPilot
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO Aircraft (acNAME, range)
    SELECT
        i.acNAME, i.range
    FROM
        inserted i;
    Declare @acID as int = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY());

    INSERT INTO Employee (empNAME, salary)
    SELECT
        i.empNAME, i.salary
    FROM
        inserted i
    Declare @empId as int = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY());

    INSERT INTO Certification (empID, acID)
    SELECT @empId, @acID
END
```

**NOTE:** Provided solution will work for Microsoft SQL Server. As you didn't mention the DBMS product name, I don't know whether this will help you or not.
Thanks